# Can you get the user’s scroll position every time they scroll with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to grab the current position of the users scroll bar when they scroll?

Say, if they were scrolled to the very top it would be 0, if they scrolled down it'd change.

Can I assign a variable to contain the current scroll position whenever I access it, or is there a function in JavaScript for this already?

Comment: Sorry, I've been looking at scrollTop for the past 15 minutes but I'm such an amateur when it comes to JavaScript. I'm trying to find a way of having the value change whilst the page is scrolled, with no luck so far.

Comment: You're looking for a scroll event listener. http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From your comment, I get you are looking for a scroll event listener such as 
http://api.jquery.com/scroll/, and then you can use http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ to find out the position of the scroll.

For example:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    //You've scrolled this much:
       $('p').text("You've scrolled " + $(window).scrollTop() + " pixels");
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pFaTF/

Comment: To improve performance, you might want to cache the the window object instead of calling the $() method in your event handler.

[More easy jQuery performance tips](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance--net-5551)

Answer (score 13):

There are properties on the `window` object for this: `window.scrollX` and `window.scrollY`.

See e.g. http://javascript.gakaa.com/window-scrollx-2-0-scrolly.aspx

Comment: Does the value of scrolledDown change dynamincally as the page is scrolled?

Comment: Sorry. On that link you gave me it creates a variable called scrolledDown. I'm assuming I need to have some kind of function update that every time the page is scrolled

Comment: @Richard: ah, gotcha — your original question didn’t make it very clear that you wanted to have some code run when the user’s scroll position changes.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the scrollTop property of the body element:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].scrollTop;
```

This returns the number of pixels that are above the visible area.So 0 when the user hasn't scrolled, `bodyheight-viewporthieght` when the scrollbar is at the bottom.

Answer (score 5):

Try using [.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/LZM7H/

---

**Edit**

If you are trying to output the position of the element being scrolled as it happens then this can be achieved using the [.scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event:

```
$('#container').scroll(function(){
    var position = $('#container').scrollTop();
});
```

Here is a live example:

http://jsfiddle.net/LZM7H/2/

Comment: Thanks jdavies! :) Works a treat.
Also, thank you to OhCaN. I saw your comment and was trying it out but I'm real slow with this.

Comment: Perhaps slightly cleaner: 
$('#container').scroll(function(){
    var position = $(this).scrollTop();
});

Answer (score 0):

as additional to Paul D Waite answer, you can told the browser to scroll the window to by using `window.scroll(0,0);`, where the value is referencing to x and y position.