# Calculate scroll on Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you get the user’s scroll position every time they scroll with JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182375/can-you-get-the-users-scroll-position-every-time-they-scroll-with-javascript-jq)

I am trying to write something in JavaScript/Jquery on the use of scroll events.

Here is where I started but I can't seem to figure out how to get scroll value.

> I am looking for is the class/method to find the current scroll
>   position on the page.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window.parent.document).scroll(function () {

        var scroll_info = X;//X == the method/class of getting scroll value

        if (scroll_info > 40) {
            //show
            $('#ArrowImage').show(1000);
        } else {
            //hide
            $('#ArrowImage').hide(1000);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: How about [`scrollTop`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)?

Comment: I tried this before I posted this question `var scroll_info =$(window).scrollTop.val();`
Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Akyl Have you tried `$(window).scrollTop()`?

Comment: literally maybe 2-3 dozen dupes out there. Google gave me like 6 pages all relating to this.

Comment: `$(window).scroll(function() { if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) { /* show arrow */ } else { /* hide arrow */ }});` because I'm nice.

Comment: Hmm...I didn't find it when I google searched. I already have got the answered by David Is Not Here.

Comment: I Googled and found several results too, however most of the methods I was trying seemed to fail on Chrome... Anyway, the simplest was the most effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could likely use both JQuery's .prop and .scrollTop methods to retrieve the position of the vertical scroll bar, for the element you're trying to scroll. Here's an example that combines a little of each of those to scroll a textbox to its bottom:

```
$('#chatTextContainer').scrollTop(
    $('#chatTextContainer').prop("scrollHeight") );
```

To find the currently scrolled top, you would use something like this:

```
$(element).prop("scrollTop")
```

What you seem to be looking for is:

```
theTop = $("html").scrollTop();
```

Comment: I tried this `var scroll_info =$(window).scrollTop.val();` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: To retrieve the value of scrollTop I'd suggest two things... (1) use .scrollTop() with parenthesis. (2) instead of window, use html. Just added an example to the end there.

Comment: Yup that's what I was looking for