# jQuery - Detect Horizontal Scroll Position (pixels), then do function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a jQuery function that I would like to have occur when the user reaches `25px` while horizontally scrolling on the page (i.e. `html, body`). Horizontal scroll = x-axis.

In other words, I would like jQuery to detect when the user reaches 25px on the x-axis and then execute my function.

How could this be accomplished? Have been looking and trying different functions for an hour with no luck. Thanks to all in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vm28X/1/

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollLeft() >= 25){
         yourFunction();   
    }
});

function yourFunction(){
    //I scrolled over 25
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7182570/265165), you only have to replace `scrollTop(...)` with `scrollLeft(...)` for the x-axis.